# What are available asset types in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I've created a function that retrieve all the GEE assets from a user account:

```py
def get_assets(folder=None, asset_list = []):

    # set the folder
    folder = folder if folder else ee.data.getAssetRoots()[0]['id']
    
    # loop in the assets
    for asset in ee.data.listAssets({'parent': folder})['assets']:
        if asset['type'] == 'FOLDER':
            asset_list = get_assets(asset['name'], asset_list)
        else:
            asset_list += [asset]
    
    return asset_list
```

I use it to get all the asset of a user and then I sort them by type:

```py
assets = get_assets(self.folder)

tables = sorted([e['id'] for e in assets if e['type'] == 'TABLE'])
images = sorted([e['id'] for e in assets if e['type'] == 'IMAGE'])
```

I recently realise that "IMAGE_COLLECTION" was also a type. So instead of trying to guess I prefer to ask:

What are all the asset types available in GEE ?

Comment: This is probably a complete list: https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/javascript/src/data.js#L1806

Comment: Thanks, I think the "FEATURE_COLLECTION" is not used anymore, I have a lot of them and they are all tagged as "TABLE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned by [Daniel Wiell](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/154371/daniel-wiell), an extensible list can be found in the api core code:

```
/**
 * The types of assets. Note that the server describes table assets as
 * feature collections, though they should be described to users as tables.
 * @enum {string}
 */
ee.data.AssetType = {
  ALGORITHM: 'Algorithm',
  FOLDER: 'Folder',
  FEATURE_COLLECTION: 'FeatureCollection',
  IMAGE: 'Image',
  IMAGE_COLLECTION: 'ImageCollection',
  TABLE: 'Table',
  UNKNOWN: 'Unknown'
};
```

The one you'll get in the Python API are the keys of the previous table

Comment: Source code link: https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/javascript/src/data.js